# Php submit button refreshing but not saving any data to database

Tags: php, html, symfony, button, submit

I'm trying to do nav-tabs and submit button just refreshing page with old datas. When you enter different inputs into the fields and submit its just refreshing and not save any data.

I followed the data through the SettingsController.php and data does not enter into this function in edit func;

```php
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Successfully Saved!');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_settings_edit', ['id' => $setting->getId()]);
    }
```

I tried several things but can not solve this please help me, thanks! :)

This is settings\_form.html.twig

```
                {{ include('admin/messages.html.twig') }}

                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Edit</h4>

                            <div class="card">
                                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab"><span class="hidden-sm-up"></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">General Informations</span></a> </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab"><span class="hidden-sm-up"></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">Email Server</span></a> </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab"><span class="hidden-sm-up"></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">About Us</span></a> </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages2" role="tab"><span class="hidden-sm-up"></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">Contact</span></a> </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages3" role="tab"><span class="hidden-sm-up"></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">References</span></a> </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- Tab panes -->
                                <div class="tab-content tabcontent-border">
                                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">
                                        <div class="p-20">
                                            <br>

                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Title</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <input type="text" name="setting[title]" value="{{ setting.title }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Title Here">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Description</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <textarea id="editor" style="height: 400px" name="setting[content]" class="form-control" placeholder="Description Here">{{ setting.description }}</textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Keywords</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input type="text" name="setting[keywords]" value="{{ setting.keywords }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Keywords Here">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Company</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input type="text" name="setting[company]" value="{{ setting.company }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Here">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Status</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="setting[status]">
                                                        <option>{{ setting.status }}</option>
                                                        <option>True</option>
                                                        <option>False</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane  p-20" id="profile" role="tabpanel">
                                        <div class="p-20">
                                            <br>

                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Email Server</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <input type="text" name="setting[smtpserver]" value="{{ setting.smtpserver }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Smtpserver Here">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Email</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <input type="text" name="setting[smtpemail]" value="{{ setting.smtpemail }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Smtpemail Here">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Email Password</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <input type="text" name="setting[smtppassword]" value="{{ setting.smtppassword }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Smtppassword Here">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Smtp Port</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <input type="text" name="setting[smtpport]" value="{{ setting.smtpport }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Smtpport Here">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane p-20" id="messages" role="tabpanel">
                                        <div class="p-20">
                                            <br>

                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">About Us</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <textarea id="editor2" style="height: 400px" name="setting[aboutus]" class="form-control" placeholder="About Us Here">{{ setting.aboutus }}</textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane p-20" id="messages2" role="tabpanel">
                                        <div class="p-20">
                                            <br>

                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Address</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input type="text" name="setting[address]" value="{{ setting.address }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Address Here">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Fax</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input type="text" name="setting[fax]" value="{{ setting.fax }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Fax Here">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane p-20" id="messages3" role="tabpanel">
                                        <div class="p-20">
                                            <br>

                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">References</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <textarea id="editor3" style="height: 400px" name="setting[referances]" class="form-control" placeholder="References Here">{{ setting.referances }}</textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>



                        </div>




                    </form>

                    <script>
                        ClassicEditor
                            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
                            .catch( error => {
                                console.error( error );
                            } );
                    </script>
                    <script>
                        ClassicEditor
                            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor2' ) )
                            .catch( error => {
                                console.error( error );
                            } );
                    </script>
                    <script>
                        ClassicEditor
                            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor3' ) )
                            .catch( error => {
                                console.error( error );
                            } );
                    </script>
```

And this is settings\edit.html.twig

```twig
{% extends 'adminbase.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Edit Settings{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="col-12 d-flex no-block align-items-center">
        <h4 class="page-title">Edit Settings
            <small><a href="{{ path('admin_settings_index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Back to List</a></small>
        </h4>
        <div class="ml-auto text-right">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ url('admin') }}">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Settings</li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10">

        <div class="card">

            <div class="border-top">

                <div class="card-body">

                    {{ include('admin/settings/_form.html.twig', {'button_label': 'Update'}) }}

                    {{ include('admin/settings/_delete_form.html.twig') }}

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

And this is SettingsController.php file

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Admin\Settings;
use App\Form\Admin\SettingsType;
use App\Repository\Admin\SettingsRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/admin/settings")
 */
class SettingsController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="admin_settings_index", methods="GET")
     */
    public function index(SettingsRepository $settingsRepository): Response
    {
        $setdata = $settingsRepository->findAll();



        if(!$setdata)
        {
            $setting = new Settings();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $setting->setTitle("Site");
            $em->persist($setting);
            $em->flush();
            $setdata = $settingsRepository->findAll();


        }



        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_settings_edit', ['id' => $setdata[0]->getId()]);
        //return $this->render('admin/settings/index.html.twig', ['setting' => $settingsRepository->findAll()]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="admin_settings_new", methods="GET|POST")
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $setting = new Settings();
        $form = $this->createForm(SettingsType::class, $setting);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($setting);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_settings_index');
        }

        return $this->render('admin/settings/new.html.twig', [
            'setting' => $setting,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_settings_show", methods="GET")
     */
    public function show(Settings $setting): Response
    {
        return $this->render('admin/settings/show.html.twig', ['setting' => $setting]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="admin_settings_edit", methods="GET|POST")
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Settings $setting): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(SettingsType::class, $setting);
        $form->handleRequest($request);



        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Successfully Saved!');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_settings_edit', ['id' => $setting->getId()]);
        }

        return $this->render('admin/settings/edit.html.twig', [
            'setting' => $setting,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_settings_delete", methods="DELETE")
     */
    public function delete(Request $request, Settings $setting): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$setting->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($setting);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_settings_index');
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code only. And you need to `persist()` something for `flush()` to actually save it.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here, I don't know which code could be better to help :/

Comment: I've add persist($setting) and flush it didn't change anything

Comment: You are presently not using your form in the view. You recreate another form only in HTML, so, there is no data binding. Form is not submitted and even less valid.

Comment: I copy pasted my form into edit twig but nothing changed. How do I use without recreating one?

Comment: Whats the name of your form Type? Etc `SettingsType.php` (in Form folder) ? Rename your input names to `settings[]` -> etc `settings[title]` and so on...

Comment: I can't thank you enough man that worked! :D

Answer (score 0):

You are not persisting object.

```
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($form->getData())
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Successfully Saved!');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_settings_edit', ['id' => $setting->getId()]);
    }
```